# How to create a bar graph for each column using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I know this is very simple and I apologize if this has been asked already. I am new to R. I am hoping to create a a bar graph from my current data frame using ggplot2.

My dataframe looks like this

```
10 uM ATR     10 uM N    10 uM P
0                  1           4
6                  0           1
2                  10          2
0                  3           0
7                  0           0
1                  1           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `ggplot2` from `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "var") %>%
        group_by(var) %>%
        summarise(mean_var = mean(value), sd_var = sd(value)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = var, y = mean_var, fill = var)) +
        geom_col(colour = "black", lwd = 2,
                 fill = c("black", "lightgray", "gray"), show.legend = FALSE) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_var, ymax = mean_var+sd_var), width = 0.2) +
        labs(x = "", y = "Number of cells")
```

[image]

For information about error bars you can look [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-error-bars-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

---

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(`10_uM_atropine` = c(0, 6, 2, 0, 7, 1), `10_uM_NE` = c(1, 
0, 10, 3, 0, 1), `10_uM_PHE` = c(4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```